# How to use an instance of a class assigned to a property of another class in the other class in php

Tags: php

I am making a framework in PHP. 
I have an import function in library/core.php.

I can use the function like this:

```
$core->import("someclass");
```

This is the function:

```
public function import()
    {
        $import_resources = func_get_args();

        $check_directories = array("library", "template", "view", "action", "errors");

        $instances = array();

        foreach($import_resources as $resource)
        {
            for($i = 0; $i <= count($check_directories) - 1; $i++)
            {
                if(file_exists($this->appRoot() . $check_directories[$i] . "/" . $resource . ".php"))
                {

                    $classes = get_declared_classes();
                    include ($check_directories[$i] . "/" . $resource . ".php");
                    $included_classes = array_diff(get_declared_classes(), $classes);
                    $last_class = end($included_classes);

                    $last_class_lowercase = strtolower($last_class);

                    $this->$last_class_lowercase = new $last_class(); 
                    // create an instance of the included class and attach it to the Core Class

                }

                else
                {

                }   
            }
        }

    }
```

So in an other class, I can use it like this:

```
$core->import("view");
$core->view->get();
```

The whole point of this, was to make the included class available in another class, when it is extended.

```
class Someclass extends Core
{
    public function somefunc()
    {
        $this->view->get(); // This does not work. 
    }
}
```

How could I make it work like this? This is a very important part of the framework, because this is how it works. I think it works similar in popular frameworks like CodeIgniter too.

I was trying to use `parent::view->get()`, but I guess I don't fully understand it.

I hope I can figure this out, because it is holding me down in my work. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is a "Core", anyways? Is it an importer? Maybe you should call it "Importer", then.

Comment: Why not just use autoloading? Even better, follow PSR-0 and use a standard autoloader.

Comment: @Waleed Khan; No no no, Core is a core class, that has all the necessary functions. It should be included in every php file in my framework. The Core import function is just an easier way to import files. Maybe I can reinvent the class naming later, but now I have to concentrate on making the framework work.

Comment: @Louis-PhilippeHuberdeau I was considering autoloading, but with this I can include only the classes, that I need.

Comment: @Rasteril That's not how OOP works.

Comment: @Rasteril: Autoloading is about including only the classes you need, when you need them, and not a moment earlier. That's kinds the point.

Comment: "I think it works similar in popular frameworks like CodeIgniter too." This would be a good moment to step away for a second and think about what it is you are trying to mimic.

Comment: @Louis-PhilippeHuberdeau A standard autoloader that is being modified/debated even right now? That's a whole new meaning to standard, really.

Comment: @Louis-PhilippeHuberdeau I finally integrated the __autoload function, as you suggested. I wanted to ask, is there a way to make instances of the __autoloaded classes, so I don't need to instantiate classes in every file?

Comment: Unless your constructors perform a lot of work, you really should not worry about the cost of instantiating classes so much. If you really need a single instance, you should implement them as Singletons. Just look it up. However, know that this is not considered to be a good practice and should be avoided as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is use "Magic Methods", this particular one (__get() this gets properties not accessible from outside). You will want to use it like this:

```
<?php
// --- Begin Importer.php --------------------
class Importer{
    protected $classes = array();

    public function __get($method_name){
        if(array_key_exists($method_name, $this->classes)){
            return $this->classes[$method_name];
        }
    }

    public function import($class_name){
        // Do this or use an auto loader
        require_once __DIR__ . "/../classes/$class_name";
        $this->classes[$class_name] = new $class_name();
    }
}
// --- End Importer.php ---------------------


// --- Begin MyClass.php --------------------
class MyClass{
    public function get(){
        return "hello";
    }
}
// --- End MyClass.php ----------------------


// --- Where ever you call Importer ---------
$importer = new Importer();
$importer->import("MyClass");


echo $importer->MyClass->get();
```